# scrollIntoView does not work in Firefox Android if scrollable element has overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, firefox

I'm setting overflow-y: hidden for body, because I want to handle the scroll programmatically and prevent the user from scrolling. Then I'm using element.scrollIntoView() to scroll to a specific element.

I've tried in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Chrome for Android, Safari iOS and it works ok, the page is scrolled to the element.

But on Firefox Android it does not scroll, doesn't do anything.

I cannot find any documentation that specifically says that Firefox doesn't support scrolling to an element inside a overflow:hidden container.

This is the code:

```
.screen {
  max-width: 600px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```
const elem = document.getElementById(`screen-${itemId}`);
if(elem) elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: smooth ? 'smooth' : 'auto' });
else console.warn('not found');
```

Comment: So is the question asking for a workaround?

Comment: information, is this a Firefox bug? what's the correct behavior? am I doing something wrong? if so, yes, a workaround would be great.

Comment: I see. I recommend including that in your original question to clarify what you're asking for.